# Как сделать так, чтобы капча появлялась только после неудачной попытки авторизации

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я использую django-simple-captcha в своем приложении, хочу освоить методы работы с ней.
Возникла следующая проблема: Хочу сделать так, чтобы она, на странице входа в аккаунт, появлялась только после неудачной попытки входа.
**Форма** капчи выглядит так:

```
class CaptchaForm(forms.Form):
    captcha = CaptchaField(
        label=('')
    )
```

**Views login**:

```
class UserLogin(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(
            request, 'users/login.html', context={'form': form}
        )

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            bound_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if bound_form.is_valid():
                cd = bound_form.cleaned_data
                user = authenticate(
                    request, email=cd['email'], password=cd['password']
                )
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    messages.success(request, 'Вы успешно вошли в систему!')
                    return redirect('mainsite:dashboard')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                messages.error(
                    request, 'Неверный адрес электронной почты или пароль'
                    )
                return redirect('users:login')
        else:
            bound_form = LoginForm()
        return render(
               request, 'users/login.html', context={'form': bound_form}
               )
```

Если сделать капчу не отдельной формой, а просто запихнуть поле капчи в форму логина, то она будет отображаться сразу, в этом случае не понятно, как можно реализовать эту идею(появление поля после неудачного входа)
Я пытался сделать две формы входа, одну с капчей другую без и в представлении выводить используя флаг, но тогда код получается совсем не **DRY**а  это не есть хорошо.

Comment: ну если получаете ошибку вы можете передать на страницу 2 формы. `bound_form = LoginForm(request.POST)` `captcha_form=CaptchaForm(request.POST)` ,` context = {bound_form': bound_form,'captcha_form': captcha_form,}`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Я попытался так сделать, ничего не отображается, отображается если я так сделаю с методом get, но тогда будут сразу две формы отображаться

Comment: не отображается даже первая форма если так сделать?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin первая отображается

Comment: а в шаблоне выводите вторую? `{{captcha_form}}`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin В шаблоне я выводил все циклом `{{for field in form}} {{field}}`

Comment: ну так это же для 1 формы. 2 тоже надо вывести, у вас же каптча в отдельной форме

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105638/discussion-between-daniil1703-and-vadim-sharoikin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение:**
Я решил использовать в данной ситуации джанго сессии.
Мне пришлось использовать две формы логина,в одной форме содержится поле для капчи,в другой - нет. Т.к если сделать отдельную форму для капчи, в представлении приходится делать в разы больше условий и получается больше строчек кода, а результат не меняется.
**Код с решением**:
**Views.py:**

```
def get(self, request):
    #если попыток входа не было вообще
    if 'try_login' not in request.session:
        #создаем ключ try_login со значением false
        request.session['try_login'] = False
        check_try_login = request.session['try_login']
        #обрабатываем форму без капчи
        form = LoginForm()
    #если попытка входа уже была
    else:
        #запоминаем значение в переменную
        check_try_login = request.session['try_login']
        if not check_try_login:
            # Если попытки входа не было, но сессия try_login есть,
            # то отображаем форму без капчи
            form = LoginForm()
        else:
            # Если попытка входа была, то отображаем форму с капчей
            form = SecureLoginForm()
    return render(
        request, 'users/login.html', context={'form': form}
    )

def post(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # запоминаем значение try_login в переменную
        check_try_login = request.session['try_login']
        if not check_try_login:
            # Если попытки входа не было, то проверяем и отправляем форму
            # в которой нет поля капчи
            bound_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if bound_form.is_valid():
                cd = bound_form.cleaned_data
                user = authenticate(
                    request, email=cd['email'], password=cd['password']
                )
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    messages.success(request, 'Вы успешно вошли в систему!')
                    del request.session['try_login']
                    return redirect('mainsite:dashboard')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                messages.error(
                    request, 'Неверный ввод данных'
                    )
                request.session['try_login'] = True
                return redirect('users:login')
        # Если попытка входа была, то проверяем и отправляем форму
        # в которой есть поле капчи
        else:
            bound_form = SecureLoginForm(request.POST)
            if bound_form.is_valid():
                cd = bound_form.cleaned_data
                user = authenticate(
                    request, email=cd['email'], password=cd['password']
                )
            else:
                # если введеная капча не проходит проверку, то
                # сбрасываем все введенные данные и вызываем ошибку
                messages.error(
                    request, 'Неверный ввод данных'
                    )
                return redirect('users:login')
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    messages.success(
                        request, 
                        'Вы успешно вошли в систему!'
                    )
                    del request.session['try_login']
                    return redirect('mainsite:dashboard')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                messages.error(
                    request, 'Неверный ввод данных'
                    )
                # Если введенные данные пользователя не проходят проверку,
                # то запоминаем попытку входа, и сбрасываем все введенные
                # данные
                request.session['try_login'] = True
                return redirect('users:login')
    else:
        bound_form = SecureLoginForm()
    return render(
           request, 'users/login.html', context={
                'form': bound_form,
                }
           )
```

**forms.py:**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=('Email'),
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )

    password = forms.CharField(
        label=('Пароль'),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )

    class Meta(object):
        model = CustomUser

        fields = [
            'email', 'password'
        ]

class SecureLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=('Email'),
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )

    password = forms.CharField(
        label=('Пароль'),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )
    captcha = CaptchaField(
        label=(''),
    )

    class Meta(object):
        model = CustomUser

        fields = [
            'email', 'password', 'captcha'
        ]
```

**P.S** Код получился совсем не DRY, и как это исправить, для меня пока что не понятно, но он решает данную проблему.